# Multiple DIVs with same class with each toggling independently between 2 DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple divs with the same class (.item) and trying to figure out how to independently toggle between 2 divs (#open and #close).

For example, clicking on "A" or "B" toggles between "Open" and "Close" independently.

I've tried placing "(this)" before (.item), but it results in toggling not working at all.

```js
$(this).on("click", function(event) {
  $(event.target).closest(".item").toggleClass("highlight").toggleClass("marked unmarked");
  if ($(".item").hasClass('unmarked')) {
    $("#open").show();
    $("#close").hide();
  } else if ($(".item").hasClass('marked')) {
    $("#close").show();
    $("#open").hide();
  } else {
    $("#close").hide();
    $("#open").hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.item {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #EEEEEE;
}

.highlight {
  background: orange;
}

#open,
#close {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item marked">A</div>
<div class="item marked">B</div>
<div class="item marked">C</div>
<div id="open">Open</div>
<div id="close">Close</div>
```

Comment: You may have to rewrite your explanation in different words, I for one am having trouble understanding what you want to happen when A,B,C are clicked.

Comment: Clicking on A, B, C should toggle between "open" and "close" independently. Currently clicking on A toggles correctly, but if I then click on B or C nothing happens

Comment: Its because you always check $(".item") but .item have multiple items.

Comment: I still don't understand exactly what you're doing with open and close but here's a fiddle to get you started.. https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/127newyj/

Comment: If I click on "A", it should toggle between #open and #close. 
If I click on "B", it should toggle between #open and #close independent from "A" and "C". 
If I click on "C", it should toggle between #open and #close independent from "A" and "B"

Comment: Clicking on "A" results in #open displaying, works fine. The problem is if I then click on "B" to toggle #open and click again to toggle #close, nothing happens because "A" is toggled #open. The desired result is "A" to still have #open, but "B" to also have #open when clicked and #close when "B" is clicked again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you maybe looking for this behaviour?..

```js
$('.item').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('highlight')) {
    $(this).removeClass('highlight');
    $('#open').hide();
    $('#close').show();
  } else {
    $('.item.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
    $('#open').show();
    $('#close').hide();
  }
})
```

```css
.item {text-align: center;margin: 5px;padding: 5px;background: #EEEEEE;}
.highlight {background: orange;}
#open, #close {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">A</div>
<div class="item">B</div>
<div class="item">C</div>
<div id="open">Open</div>
<div id="close">Close</div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/127newyj/

Comment: Thank you so much Hastig! It's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly

My recommendation for this scenario is not to rely on the "this" keyword. $(this).on('click'.... is ridiculously broad. It needs to be contained in other code that would allow for a 'this' to be relative.

Instead, get your element by

```
var my_elemens = getElementsByClassName('item')
```

and refer to them by

```
my_elemens[0] // A
my_elemens[1] // B
my_elemens[2] // C
```

And then for whatever you're wanting to click, use it, so possibly...

```
$(myelemens[0]).on('click'....
```